# way to check "value" of undefines

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a clean way to check for this ?

I am using typescript, and I have a big object with many optional value

I want to access,

```
value1.subValue1.subsubValue1;
```

but if subValue1 that is optional is undefined, I get an error.

For the moment, I only know something like

```
if(value1 && value1.subValue1 && value1.subValue1.subsubValue1);
```

But is there something shorter ?

```
value1?.subValue1?.subsubValue1 but it doesn't work in my code
```

Comment: No, there's no "elvis" (i.e. null coalescing) operator. The way you did it is as short as it gets.

Comment: but In some code for angular, there is the following : *ngIf="passwordForm?.controls.oldPassword?.errors?.required"

Comment: Yes, it's duplicated, I didn't know that thing was called Elvis operator. now I can search for it thanks

Comment: FWIW, I'd really like to see it added, but such is life. And yeah, I have no idea why they called it that other than it originated in the groovy language and I guess they thought it sounded cool.